# Is there a way to consider JSON arrays unordered in Go?

Tags: arrays, json, go, unordered, object-hash

I'm trying to replicate the object-hash npm package in Go and need to be able to support *unordered arrays* (i.e. ordering of arrays shouldn't matter while deciding whether one JSON is different from another).

Example: The two JSON strings `{ foo: 1.23e1, bar: { baz: [0, 1, { a: 1 }, { b: 2 }], abc: 12 } }` and `{ foo: 1.23e1, bar: { baz: [1, 0, { b: 2 }, { a: 1 }], abc: 12 } }` should give the same output (byte array).

Currently, I'm achieving this through [a lot of recursive code](https://go.dev/play/p/EhX83C8f4Ch), trying to cover all edge cases. Is there a better way of doing this?

Edits:

1. To clarify the problem statement further, I'm trying to generate SHA-1 hashes of JSON strings. These JSONs are arbitrarily structured (so can't unmarshal them into a well-defined `struct`). While generating these hashes, my client wants me to ignore the ordering of arrays - since any array with the same elements in any order represents the same thing in their system (they're using JSON arrays as unordered lists).
2. Since I can't assume anything about the structure of these input JSONs, I'm sorting the arrays before hashing them (in my current implementation). For sorting, I'm comparing json-marshalled string representations of the array elements. Before sorting, I'm also checking if any element of the array is itself an array or map, and recursively handling them. (This is what's making it a lot of code)
3. The [object-hash implementation](https://github.com/puleos/object-hash/blob/5e82c257251ab213bbd77a0f742d34c464af56cd/index.js#L269) in Node seems to be following the same process as me.

Comment: But they are ordered, and other systems will consider them ordered, what exactly are you trying to do? If it's only for comparison, sorting them for consistency doesn't look like a lot of code.

Comment: XY-Problem? What is the end goal of you trying to do this?

Comment: Your problem is not well stated. You are looking forward to replicate the javascript implementation which allows to sort a slice (to use the go terminolgy) of empty interfaces. IE: how to compare an integer with a map string interface{}. I am not totally convinced that the current scheme which consists of the comparison of the string representation of the json marshalling of the two values will produce an accurate result.  the javascript implementation might be more subtle than that. Maybe that can help in the future https://go.dev/play/p/aaoXrBRzJN7

Comment: Your solution looks ok. Don't think there's a better way. Generally in Go weird requirement == weird code.

Comment: @JimB the object-hash package provides support for unordered-arrays, which is what I was referring to. It is not incorrect, just a different use case.

Comment: I see what you mean, but In that case it's just sorting them, so that the order can be compared, because arrays always have an order.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to consider JSON arrays unordered in Go?

No. Sorry, there is no magic to turn an array into something else. (Actually there is not much magic at all in Go).